# Spring: SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal() returns null

Tags: java, spring, principalcontext

In My MVC application, even after login when I am trying to get the principal object using,

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

the authentication is returned as null.

In Spring-security context,

```
<intercept-url pattern="/test/user/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
```

Servlet mapping in Web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I am new to MVC implementation. Please help me in fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Spring Security instantiate a new context every time there is a **"redirect"**.
So **getContext()** returns a **new object** rather the one you used in login. Someone suggested to **get the context from session**.
See the answer to this post.
"[Spring's SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() returns null after RedirectView is used in HTTPS/SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952718/springs-securitycontextholder-getcontext-getauthentication-returns-null-aft)"