# Spring Security AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException, SecurityContextHolder.getContext is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a strange error, hours of debugging and I can't understand.

**UPDATE 1:** I use Spring Security 4.0.3, running on Tomcat 7.

The problem is close to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952718/springs-securitycontextholder-getcontext-getauthentication-returns-null-aft?rq=1), maybe the `SecurityContextHolder` is lost during `response.redirect()` but the answer doesn't help.

The problem seems close to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500519/an-authentication-object-was-not-found-in-the-securitycontext-spring-3-2-2) too but the answer has no sense to me.

This is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class ProjectSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").anonymous();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(Constants.PROFIL_ADMIN).password(Constants.PROFIL_ADMIN).
            roles("ADMIN","TEST_SERVICE");
    }
}
```

After log in I try to get a secured URL:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myurl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public boolean getTestService(HttpServletRequest request)
        throws SQLException, PoRulesException {

    System.out.println("get security context");
    System.out.println("--------------------");
    SecurityContext secuContext = (SecurityContext) request.getSession().getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT");
    System.out.println(secuContext);
    System.out.println("get security context holder");
    System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext());

    return testService.getTestMethod();
}
```

the method inside the service

```
@Secured("ROLE_TEST_SERVICE")
public boolean getTestMethod() {
    Sysout.out.println("Hiii")
    return true
}
```

Now, the log when it doesn't work:

```
INFO    2016-07-11 15:57:00,006 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] com.po.mvc.controller.LoginController  - Login
INFO    2016-07-11 15:57:00,057 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] com.po.mvc.controller.LoginController  - User : axel
INFO    2016-07-11 15:57:00,065 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] com.po.mvc.controller.LoginController  - Authenticate : true
INFO    2016-07-11 15:57:00,065 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] com.po.mvc.controller.LoginController  - Authenticate : org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@bbbc4f45: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@fc8a: Username: ADM; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_CONSULTER_CA,ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 613DFE47B2CE6E29DA3C227F8E028590; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_TEST_SERVICE
get security context
--------------------
org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@bbbc4f45: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@bbbc4f45: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@fc8a: Username: ADM; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_CONSULTER_CA,ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 613DFE47B2CE6E29DA3C227F8E028590; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_TEST_SERVICE
get security context holder
org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@ffffffff: Null authentication
ERROR   2016-07-11 15:57:01,960 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] com.po.exception.GlobalControllerExceptionHandler  - org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:222)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at com.po.service.CAService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f6e21857.getVarAndPrevCa(<generated>)
    at com.po.mvc.controller.CaController.getVarAndPrevCa(CaController.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and when it works. I just see no difference ... the Spring context is set and contains credential as sysout proove but `SecurityContextHolder` is not set.

```
INFO    2016-07-11 16:09:45,374 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] com.po.mvc.controller.LoginController  - Login
INFO    2016-07-11 16:09:45,393 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] com.po.mvc.controller.LoginController  - User : axel
INFO    2016-07-11 16:09:45,395 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] com.po.mvc.controller.LoginController  - Authenticate : true
INFO    2016-07-11 16:09:45,395 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] com.po.mvc.controller.LoginController  - Authenticate : org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@bbbc4f45: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@fc8a: Username: ADM; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_TEST_SERVICE; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 613DFE47B2CE6E29DA3C227F8E028590; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_TEST_SERVICE
get security context
--------------------
org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@bbbc4f45: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@bbbc4f45: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@fc8a: Username: ADM; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_TEST_SERVICE Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 613DFE47B2CE6E29DA3C227F8E028590; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_CONSULTER_CA, ROLE_USER
get security context holder
org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@4440cc59: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@4440cc59: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@fc8a: Username: ADM; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_CONSULTER_CA,ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@166c8: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 19994511EEE72462E8D680CDADCFEC4C; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_CONSULTER_CA, ROLE_USER

INFO    2016-07-11 16:09:46,879 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] Hiii
```

The only difference between when it works and when it doesn't is:

- works when I connect from a page of my website, exemple I'm on `mywebsite.com` which is public and going to `mywebsite.com/login?user=me` it works
- but doesn't work if I come from Google on `mywebsite.com/login?user=me`

The session property `SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT` is set in both cases but not `SecurityContextHolder` which fired an exception inside `@Secured` [line 222](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/intercept/AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java)

I don't want to use a trick like check manually `SecurityContextHolder` in a method (after redirect) and if is `null` set the session property `SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT` which is not `null`, I want fix the issue at the root.

Comment: Setting authentication object in SecurityContext inside a controller instead of a classic Spring security schema of Filter > Manager > Provider sounds extrange to me.

Comment: Even though, I see an extrange thing. According to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken api, it has two constructors; one taking and (Object principal, Object credentials) which produces a non-authenticated token and another one taking (Object principal, Object credentials, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) which return an authenticated token. You are using ther first one, so your token could be not authenticated

Comment: We access to a portal with SSO, then each app with LDAP from sso string, ldap login is achieve by an internal API ( CorpLDAP in my sample ) wich return a user if authorized or null if not. So, I don't have the hand on login process which is strongly secured. Here Spring security is not for login, so the "login -  password" doesn't care. LDAP return a user ( or not if not authorized ) with a profil. And I use spring security for define which profil can access to a service.

Comment: What sort of SSO? If you're using SAML or OAuth, it would probably make a lot more sense to integrate properly with that, rather than trying to work around Spring Security. If not, then it will be a bit trickier.

Comment: Honnestly, it's a very big company who have locked process, and i m not free with security,  we MUST deal with the ldap api provided, it's the standard process.

Comment: Using LDAP and every API you already have it's ok within Spring Security. What @ipsi says to be a bit tricky is to call the ldap authentication from inside a controller instead of a Filter > AuthenticationManager > Provider > UserDetailsService schema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the solution here

https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/

my configuration was missing this point

> The last step is we need to map the springSecurityFilterChain. We can
>   easily do this by extending AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer
>   and optionally overriding methods to customize the mapping.
>
> The most basic example below accepts the default mapping and adds
>   springSecurityFilterChain with the following characteristics:
>
> springSecurityFilterChain is mapped to “/*” springSecurityFilterChain
>   uses the dispatch types of ERROR and REQUEST The
>   springSecurityFilterChain mapping is inserted before any servlet
>   Filter mappings that have already been configured

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer 
   extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

Just adding that class solved the problem, if not you can add @Order

**“Ordering of WebApplicationInitializer”**

> If any servlet Filter mappings are added after
>   AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer is invoked, they might be
>   accidentally added before springSecurityFilterChain. Unless an
>   application contains Filter instances that do not need to be secured,
>   springSecurityFilterChain should be before any other Filter mappings.
>   The @Order annotation can be used to help ensure that any
>   WebApplicationInitializer is loaded in a deterministic order.

```
@Order(1)
public class SpringWebMvcInitializer extends
   AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { HelloWebSecurityConfiguration.class };
  }
  ...
}

    @Order(2)
    public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer 
       extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    }
```

Comment: The `SecurityWebApplicationInitializer` solved it for me, cheers!

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're not able to integrate with your existing SSO provider, the following solution is probably the best you can hope for.

Fundamentally, what you're doing is not going to work unless you limit yourself to a single thread in your container (which is a terrible idea). From the docs on `SecurityContextHolder`:

> Associates a given `SecurityContext` with the current execution thread.

This is important - the *current* execution thread. If you make a login request, which is handled by Thread A, then you attempt to go to the secured page, but this request is handled by Thread B, then the `SecurityContext` you set on A will *not* be available on B.

Spring Security is quite capable of handling this for you, by storing the security context in the session and storing / fetching it as required (see `org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter`). You would need make some changes to your configuration, though.

Primarily, you would need to create a new class which extends from `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`, and override the `attemptAuthentication` method. This new filter would then need to be registered, and would need to replace the existing `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. That class would also be a good place to look to get some idea of how this all hangs together, and what you can configure.

This new filter would do something along the lines of

```
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    UserLDAP ldapUser = CorpLDAP.findUser(request);
    User user = new User(ldapUser.getProfil(), ldapUser.getPwd(), Collections.emptyList());
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, "", Collections.emptyList());
}
```

This will return a fully authenticated user, which can be used later on. This is what will be stored in the `SecurityContextHolder`, and can be easily retrieved. It will also be stored in the session (if configured), so I would recommended making sure it's serializable. Since you don't make use of the password, I would *strongly* recommend against storing it in the `User`.

Hopefully that will set you in the right direction.

Comment: The answer seems interesting but finally i found a solution far away from that, the SecurityContextHolder was lost because in the some case ( /login in GET from outside the website ) configuration's bean was loaded in the wrong order. I don't really get it. If you or someone can explain why extend AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer  really solve the problem I'll give it the bounty.